# How to fix trigger or procedure in Oracle express to automate values in a column of a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

How can I to automate the column sale.sale_total which would be the sum of the values column sales_line.line_total. Can you make a trigger or procedure for these two questions?
can you help me?

Something like:  sale.sale_total = (sale.sale_total + .sales_line.line_total).

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id    NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    category_id   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    p_desc        VARCHAR2(40),
    cpu           VARCHAR2(14),
    ram           VARCHAR2(14),
    capacity      VARCHAR2(14),
    screen_size   VARCHAR2(14),
    battery       VARCHAR2(14),
    unit_price    NUMBER(7, 2),
    colour        VARCHAR2(14),
    qty_stock     NUMBER(4)
);
ALTER TABLE product ADD CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY ( product_id );

CREATE TABLE sale (
    sale_id       NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    sale_date     DATE,
    customer_id   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    employee_id   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    sale_total    NUMBER(7, 2)
);

ALTER TABLE sale ADD CONSTRAINT sale_pk PRIMARY KEY ( sale_id );

CREATE TABLE sales_line (
    sale_id      NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    product_id   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    line_qty     NUMBER(4),
    line_total   NUMBER(7, 2)
);

ALTER TABLE sales_line ADD CONSTRAINT index_3 PRIMARY KEY ( sale_id,
                                                            product_id );

ALTER TABLE product
    ADD CONSTRAINT product_p_category_fk FOREIGN KEY ( category_id )
        REFERENCES p_category ( category_id );

ALTER TABLE sale
    ADD CONSTRAINT sale_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customer_id )
        REFERENCES customer ( customer_id );

ALTER TABLE sale
    ADD CONSTRAINT sale_employee_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ( employee_id )
        REFERENCES employee ( employee_id );

ALTER TABLE sales_line
    ADD CONSTRAINT sales_line_product_fk FOREIGN KEY ( product_id )
        REFERENCES product ( product_id );

ALTER TABLE sales_line
    ADD CONSTRAINT sales_line_sale_fk FOREIGN KEY ( sale_id )
        REFERENCES sale ( sale_id );    

**Here are the triggers I have written so far:**

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sale_total_ai AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE sale
        SET sale_total = (sale_total + :NEW.line_total)         
        WHERE sale.sale_id = :NEW.sale_id;        
END;
```

I tried do like @Gordon Linoff (code below), but the value in the table sale.line_total continue null. I tried with BEFORE UPDATE, the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sale_total_ai AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE sale     
        SET sale_total = (sale_total + 
                          (CASE WHEN sale_id = :NEW.sale_id THEN :NEW.line_total ELSE 0 END) -
                          (CASE WHEN sale_id = :OLD.sale_id THEN :OLD.line_total ELSE 0 END)
                         )  
        WHERE sale_id IN (:OLD.sale_id, :NEW.sale_id);
```

I just want update the sale.sale_total column with the sum of the values of the sales_line.line_total, after I insert data in the sales_line table.

```
**Here are the triggers I have written so far:**

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sale_total_ai AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE sale
        SET sale_total = (sale_total + :NEW.line_total)         
        WHERE sale.sale_id = :NEW.sale_id;        
END;
```

Thank you

Comment: I took a look at your @Ben site. It depends if I have the help I need to do this trigger. I do not want a system, I do not want a whole database, because as you've seen, I've done it, I'd just like a trigger help because I'm having trouble getting it to work and understand. If you can help me I'm very grateful. So professionals like you, can show their skills and get customers, like me.
I do not have much knowledge in oracle express, but I'm trying and looking for anyone who can help I understand and make it work.

Comment: Preferably don't physically store values, that can be computed from other columns. It bears the severe risk of producing inconsistencies! For example it seems like you totally forgot, that you'd also need a trigger on `product` to reflect changes to the `unit_price`. You haven't thought of a delete trigger on `sales_line` that updates `sale` accordingly. You'd have inconsistencies right away. And maybe there are even more problems. You better use views if this is for convenience.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @sticky bit I will make view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to execute

```
ALTER TABLE SALE
  DROP COLUMN SALE_TOTAL;
```

This is not a column you want to have because, as you're just beginning to realize, maintaining it is going to be a nightmare. Instead, you want a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COMPUTE_SALE_TOTAL(pinSale_id IN SALE.SALE_ID%TYPE)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  nSale_total  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(LINE_TOTAL)
    INTO nSale_total
    FROM SALES_LINE
    WHERE SALE_ID = pinSale_id;

  RETURN nSale_total;
END COMPUTE_SALE_TOTAL;
```

Then, any time you need to know what the total for a sale is, you call this function.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you @Bob Jarvis for you advice and help.  I will make view instead this trigger.